# SwiftUI Lists & OnAppear

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have noticed some odd behavior on OnAppear events for List views. I'd think the OnAppear closure would run whenever a view appears on the screen, but it appears to run all at once when the List is loaded.

For example the following code:

```
@State var rows: [String] = Array(repeating: "Item", count: 20)

var body: some View {

    List(0..<rows.count, id: \.self) { index in
        Text(verbatim: self.rows[index])
            .onAppear {
                print("BOOOOM")
            }
            .frame(height:400)
    }
}
```

...I would expect the print command to run a couple times on load, then continue to print as I scrolled down. Instead it prints 20 times at once, then again as I start to scroll down.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Related discussion on Apple developer forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/716692?login=true&page=1#730825022

Answer (score 1):

I think it is behaving as expected.

For me it printed 15 times on a Simulator with `iPhone 7` and all 20 times on a Simulator with an `iPhone 11`.

I made a slight change to the `print("BOOOOM \(index)")`

There is probably a balance with performance and resources that the List abides by in the background.

Load too little and the user will "Get stuck" if scrolling too fast vs loading too much and slowing the scroll animation.

Answer (score 1):

This is has been a thorn in my proverbial claw for a good month now

I can't explain why this is happening, but it's something to do with Lists in iOS 14, and custom cell heights. If you remove `.frame(height: 400)` you'll notice that "Boom" is printed the correct number of times. When your cell height has been enlarged beyond just a normal Label, iOS will still load the same number of cells, but then backtrack for those off screen (have a look at the `.onDisappar()` view modifier).

**What can you do?**

**1. Update to iOS 15**

This behaviour is correct in iOS 15 and 13, so if you can, just up your minimum deployment target and say goodbye to iOS 14

**2. Switch to `LazyVStack`**

True to their name: `LazyVStack` and `LazyVGrid` don't do anything more than they have to, and will "Boom" the correct number of times. The downside is that you lose iOS 13 compatibility, and all the automatic layout magic that comes with `List`

If you have since found a way to make `onAppear()` work correctly in `List` for iOS 14, PLEASE let me know

Comment: Can you give an example to how LazyVStack should be used in the original question?