# Reusability support in List in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm currently working on a project that uses SwiftUI. I was trying to use `List` to display a list of let's say 10 items.

Does `List` supports reusability just like the `UITableview`?

I went through multiple posts and all of them says that `List` supports reusability: [Does the List in SwiftUI reuse cells similar to UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56655421/does-the-list-in-swiftui-reuse-cells-similar-to-uitableview)

But the memory map of the project says something else. All the Views in the `List` are created at once and not reused.

[image]

### Edit

Here is how I created the `List`:

```
List {
    Section(header: TableHeader()) {
        ForEach(0..<10) {_ in
            TableRow()
        }
    }
}
```

`TableHeader` and `TableRow` are the custom views created.

Comment: Can you please add the code how you use list?

Comment: @RajaKishan I've added the code.

Comment: Reusability means that they reuse view which are *outside* of visible area, so we have unique views for visible rows (+1 of each side), bug once view goes out of visibility boundary it is reused to draw new row appeared from opposite edge.

Comment: @Asperi So, why the memory map and the allocations instrument shows all the view instances created at once? Can you please add a link or doc for more clarification on  how this works.

Comment: @PGDev do one thing add 100 rows and then check.

Comment: Have you tried `LazyVStack` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvstack ?

Comment: How many rows are loaded depends on the device that is being used and the size of the view. Apple balances resources so the user can swipe as fast as they want

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60048979/swiftui-lists-onappear/60049756#60049756

Comment: @RajaKishan  I checked for 1000 rows. It is definitely reusing the cells. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @loremipsum Now matter what the size of cell is, the List always persist 17 cells at a time on an iPhone-12. Similarly for iPhone 8, 13 cells are persisted at a time. Earlier it used to depend on both cell and screen size. Can you please clarify in this as well.

Comment: @Kawa In `LazyVStack` the views are rendered lazily. But it doesn't support the reusability concept. For example, if I need to present 1000 items and scrolled to the last item, there will be 1000 items persisting in the memory which is a performance hit.

Comment: I don’t have much to elaborate. I know there was a WWDC video I saw a few years back that mentioned it but I couldn’t tell you which one it was. One of the SwiftUI ones but no idea which one. I’m sure that if you add items to the view you’ll get less. But, SwiftUI has gotten much more efficient recently so maybe it has changed. Also, for 1000 items I would switch to UIKit. SwiftUI is known for slowing down quite a bit with large lists. you’ll find plenty of solutions in SO such as wrapping the destination in a lazy view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List actually provides same technique as UITableView for reusable identifier. Your code make it like a scroll view.
The proper way to do is providing items as iterating data.

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
}
```

```
@State private var items = (1...1000).map { Item(name: "Item \($0)") }
...
List(items) {
   Text($0.name)
}
```

View hierarchy debugger shows only 17 rows in memory
[image]

Comment: On what basis is this showing 17 rows in the memory?

Comment: 17 rows are being displayed in my simulator screen.

Comment: Can you please try increasing the height of rows and then check how many rows are created in memory.