# Make SwiftUI List view reusable

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui-list

The below list view loads 1000 rows and I see 1000 `NameTextView` being created.

But with reusability we should be seeing very few `NameTextView`. Is there a way to optimize the code and number of rows that will be created.

I am doing similar thing as posted in Answer for question [Reusability support in List in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68539961/reusability-support-in-list-in-swiftui)

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ListContentView: View {
    var items = createList()
    var body: some View {
        List(items) { element  in
            NameTextView(name: element.name)
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
}

struct NameTextView: View {
    var name: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ListContentView()
}

struct ListElement: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
}



func createList()  -> [ListElement] {
    var items: [ListElement] = []
    
    for i in 0..<1000 {
        items.append(ListElement(name: "Name \(i)"))
        
    }
    return items
}
```

Comment: To not create all the NamaTextVirw use a LazyVStack which will only create them on demand as you scroll. This is what is most like reusability.

Comment: `Lazy` and `Reusable` are completely different concepts @PtitXav

Comment: @NNikN did you get your answer?

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftUI views make use of **UIKit components** under the covers, but that doesn't mean that SwiftUI views are just direct wrappers around UIKit components.

In the case of a `List` you have some SwiftUI view (`NameTextView` in your case) being shown in a `UICollectionViewCell`, but there is not a 1:1 correspondence between the number of `NameTextView`s and the number of underlying cells that are needed.

SwiftUI views are immutable structs and so a unique struct instance is required for each `NameTextView` - In your case, a total of 10,000 will be required, but only if you scrolled to the end of the list; additional views are created as you scroll and they need to be shown.

These are displayed on a number of `UICollectionViewCells` - You don't have direct visibility of the creation or reuse of these cells, but I would expect that there would be about n+4 of them for a list with n visible rows (the extra cells allow for off-screen cells in preparation for scrolling).

So, the short answer is you cannot make SwiftUI views reusable because SwiftUI views are immutable structs. Every time there is any change in a SwiftUI view, a new view is created to replace the old one.

The underlying collection view cells are re-used.

Answer (score 1):

❌ It seems like you did an incorrect measurement because

##### ✅ `List` is reusable in SwiftUI!

Whether its backed by `UICollectionView` for newer SwiftUI versions or `UITableView` for older versions (or the AppKit counterparts for the macOS), `List` always reuses its items (not the parent hosting view itself)

[**Here is more information**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56656890/5623035) (for the SwiftUI 1 but the latest does the same with collection view)

You can see there are only a few (reusable) items.

[image: Demo]
<sub>⚠️ The image is cropped to pay attention to the focused area but as you can see, obviously there is not 1000 items.</sub>